# Running a python 3.x script on a web server

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, tkinter, serversocket

I have created a python program (that uses tkinter) on my computer, however I would like to have it run on a web server so that people can access it on their browsers. How do I go about doing this? (The full process from script to server)

If this isnt possible, what are the other options?

Comment: I have looked for something similar.  I hope you have better luck than I had.